# C# How to refresh a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, refresh

I've writtent the following code :

`this.listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Orange;`

I would like to know how can I refresh my listview so I can see in real time the updated listview.
Thanks.

Comment: What UI technology do you use? WinForms? WPF? 
What do you mean when you say "updated"? New data in listview? 
Please provide more information.

Comment: I'm using WinForms and by updated I just mean that i change the backcolor of an Item of the listview.

Answer (score 4):

Normally you should not do anything special, and ListView will be redrawn itself when you're changing item's backcolor.

But anyway, you can use `listView1.Refresh();` to force its redrawing.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```html
listView1.Items.Clear();
```