# Why is my listView not updating after changing itemsource?

Tags: c#

I have a listview which receives information from a HashSet, but when I delete one item of the HashSet, my listview is not updated.

And my listview doesn't have a method of refresh, don't know why. Here is my code:

```
private void deleteActivityFromAlumn(String activityName, String nif)
{
    Alumn alumnDelete = Alumn.findAlumnByNIF(nif);
    Activity activityDelete = Activity.getActivityByName(activityName);
    Debug.WriteLine(alumnDelete.Name + activityDelete.Name);
    alumnDelete.activities.Remove(activityDelete);
    activityDelete.Alumns.Remove(alumnDelete);
    listActivities.ItemsSource = alumnDelete.activities;
}
```

And the item is deleted in a right way because if I go search for the object again, it is removed from the listView, but I believe that its supposed to be updated when you refresh the ItemsSource.

Comment: Doesn't `listActivities.Refresh();` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that control with bound items changes when those items change you have to

1. Either make that collection implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8). The simplest way to do it is to use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `HashSet<T>`

   - Though you will lose the uniqueness property that `HashSet<T>` gives you.
2. Or to somehow force a refresh of that control when you change the collection. Though one has to take into account that it is **not the best solution**, as it will **more often than not cause a full redrawing of the control with obvious performance and/or display issues**.

   - Either by calling the `Refresh` method ([WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488463/how-i-can-refresh-listview-in-wpf), [WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104779/c-sharp-how-to-refresh-a-listview))
   - Or by re-binding the collection

```
listActivities.ItemsSource = null; 
listActivities.ItemsSource = alumnDelete.activities
```